# Why do distant object look larger when viewed from an elevated position?

Tags: optics, vision

Can anyone explain the principle that results in a distant object being perceived as larger when viewed from an elevated position? eg: I notice when viewing a Shipping Vessel from the shoreline it appears significantly smaller than when viewed from an elevated position of approx 30 meters & 1/2 mile inland from the shoreline; I have also noted the phenomenon for an island 12 miles from shore - 20 miles inland and significantly elevated from sea level the island appears much larger than when viewed from the shoreline.

Comment: Because when you’re higher up you can see more of it. It takes up a greater % of your “ sphere of vision” if you like.

Comment: I have no idea if this is a similar effect, but the moon looks larger when it is close to the horizon. See [Moon illusion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_illusion)

Comment: @Adam Rubinson: is this your intuition or are there actual psychology studies demonstrating this effect?

Comment: @Exocytosis The moon effect is also a consequence of the fact that it appears next to other objects (trees, houses, etc.) with which you can compare it. In the middle of the sky there is nothing else and hence it appears smaller.

Comment: Psychology? It’s mathematics. How large something appears in your field of vision depends on how much of your field of vision it takes up, which depends on the size of the outline of the object (i.e. “how much you can see of it”) and how far away you are from it. So for OP’s first example, this will depend on a) how far away the ship was to begin with and b) the shape of the ship.

Comment: @Ndewolf: I am sure you noticed I did post a link to the explanation of the moon effect. Assuming that, are you saying something along the lines that being elevated would allow the ship to be compared to other objects and then look larger? I do not see what other objects you would be refering too here, unless you focus only on the inland part and not the elevation per se. Watching the sea from above does not get much elements of size comparison.

Comment: A ship doesn’t look big from the front because the front view doesn’t take up much of your field of vision. However, ships are very long so when looked at from more of a bird’s eye view they will take up more of your field of vision

Comment: @Exocytosis My apologies, I must have missed the reference. However, i just wanted to point out that there is also a non-elevation related (possible) effect related to the moon. Something that is not in effect in the case of the illusion mentioned by the OP.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson: this is psychology, not mathematics because you are refering to different parts of the object. You basically say we measure objects size based on the area they cover on the retina whatever the object orientation/inclination, which is false in general, and that makes you believe this makes it mathematical. I work in neurobiology and I can tell you we do not judge an object size or distance (and I give a hint here of their overlap) only through its retinal size.

Comment: @slarty: have you experimented with other people and see if they observe the same difference?

Comment: I never said we *measure* objects (their actual size) based on how they appear on the retina. I mean, they *appear* bigger on the retina if they take up more of your field/sphere of vision. Surely this is obvious? If you look at a piece of paper on a flat table from the side at the same horizontal level, the piece of paper will appear as a thin straight line. If you view it from above, it will look like a... piece of paper and will take up hundreds of times more of your field/sphere of vision.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson: they do not appear bigger on the retina, they ARE bigger on the retina and the field of vision is limited to what light can reach retinas so where are you going with this? Regarding your piece of paper, it will cast a different image on the retina depending on the sheet orientation and yes it will be a thinner image if looked from the sides. However I cannot think of any adult that would ask why the sheet looks smaller when watched from the side, ie. assuming they are watching the SAME thing, which they do not. I am sorry but I think the OP is a bit smarter than that.

Comment: Well perhaps I misinterpreted the meaning behind the question then. But as far as I can tell, his ship example is very similar to my paper example, although the paper example is more brazen.

Comment: @Exocytosis - yes, I've pointed this effect out to various people who agree but have no explanation, I've reviewed the Moon explanation previously but this doesn't appear to be the same cause, I would note that on reflection I've not noticed this effect for object's on land but also highlight that whilst the Island example sits on the horizon the boat example is not; the elevation aspect also seems to offset the distance, eg: why do objects appears smaller the further away they are.

Comment: @Slarty: does it depend on how crowdy the sea is?

Comment: @Exocytosis: No - this can be a single ship with no reference objects in the vicinity

Comment: @Adam Rubinson: feel free to post your answer, I might be wrong about the OP's intent.

Comment: @Slarty: yes I figured they could, but does the ship have to be isolated? ie. does the lack of other references affect your judgment?

Comment: What is the moon example you guys are talking about?

Answer (score -1):

My first guess had nothing to do with physics but psychology. I think you could have a slight vertigo raising your arousal when you are elevated and this would make things look bigger. Like a living lion looks bigger than a cow when you walk past it. Also the vertigo would be amplified by the lack of clear localisation of objects floating in large body of water. This uncertainty adds to the anxiety and has a magnifying effect, purely mental.